# Checkbox value to db by JQUERY, JSON, C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I have the following codes:
ASP.NET:

```
<body>
<form id="frm" runat="server">

    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_seat" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhdr_seat" runat="server">
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>dynamic checkbox controls generated with ids such as check_0, check_1...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_submit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  />
    </asp:Panel>
    <div id="results"></div>
</form>
```

JQUERY:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("btn_submit").click(function () {
            x = $("frm").serializeArray();
            $.each(x, function (i, field) {
                $("#results").append(field.name + ":" + field.value + " ");
            });
        });
    });
```

I want output in div as check_0:checked or check_0:true. Help me with this code please.

Comment: `$("btn_submit") and $("frm")` should be `$("#btn_submit")/$("#frm")`

Comment: `$("frm")` should be `$("#frm")` as per id selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn_submit").click(function () { // add the # for id selector
            x = $("#frm").serializeArray();  // here too.
            $.each(x, function (i, field) {
                $("#results").append(field.name + ":" + field.value + " ");
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: works well but I don't know why the div id=result is just blinking a moment with the values and again disappears?

Comment: I think your form just get submitted and page refreshes, so the changes done with the js/jQuery gets reset.